How to force cdef execution when executing cpdef method of an extension type from getattr
Let's say I define a cython extension type as follows:
cdef class A:

    def __init__(self):
    
        getattr(self, 'meth1')()

    cpdef void meth1(self):

        print('Calling meth1')

Which version of meth1 will be executed? The c or python version?
I think it's the python version, since getattr looks for the attribute of a Python object.
If it's indeed the Python version that's being executed, how can I force the C version to be executed with this kind of implementation?
EDIT
cdef class A:

    def __init__(self):

        print("meth1 : ", getattr(self, 'meth1'))
        print("meth2 : ", self.meth2)

    cpdef void meth1(self):
        pass

    cdef void meth2(self):
        pass


meth1 :  <bound method A.meth1 of <_cython_magic_....A object at ...>>
meth2 :  <bound method __Pyx_CFunc_void__lParenA__rParen_to_py_4self.<locals>.wrap of <_cython_magic_....A object at ...>>

Python version is actually the one that is recovered from getattr... How can I force c version execution ? I know I can wrap c function with a cpdef function but is there another way ?

getattr cannot get the C version. It's a Python method of looking up a Python attribute. There's no way for this to work.

CYTHON_METH_FASTCALL has to do with the vectorcall mechanism which is an alternative way of calling Python functions. It has nothing to do with cpdef/cdef functions. So your title is pretty nonsensical for the question.

I still don't think this can work, so it would be useful to know why you want this. There might be a better way of achieving a similar thing. Probably a lookup table of function pointers.

It was more out of curiosity than anything else.
Even if it's not critical, I have a cython code where I make billions of calls to getattr to look for the right method of a cdef class and I was just wondering if it was possible to directly access the c version of a cpdef rather than the python version.
